# Android, Cognito: can sign in, but can't make authenticated AWS calls

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-lambda

In an Android app, I can successfully authenticate with Cognito, which returns a CognitoIdToken and a CognitoAccessToken.

But I can't figure out how to use that to make actual authenticated call to, say Lambda or S3. It seems that there's a chasm between CognitoIdentityProvider (which I seem to be able to work with) and CognitoCredentialsProvider (which I do not).

Thanks for ideas, or even a pointer to a sample that uses Cognito and *authenticated* calls / roles.

[edit] Bonus question: Can someone explain why there is an AWSCognito* and an AmazonCognito*, and why they seem almost completely unrelated?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your Federated identities pool in the aws console.  Look  in the identity browser for the identityId that you are getting authenticated with (from your logs).

Here is the key thing: if the identity id does not show logins, then you never have gotten authenticated.  *When I say logins, there is a login count on each identity, and it shows the identityProviderName that the authentication occured with if you click on the identityID.

This is a simple test, if you have logins you are authenticated. if you don't, you aren't.  Now why none of the documentation at AWS says that... well.. who knows.

if you ARE authenticated, then the SDK stores the tokens, and you don't need to worry about it you can begin working with aws with your service configuration.

(The response is based upon the IOS sdk, but I believe for these matters, they are the same - [The diagrams in here may help you](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/master/cognito%20diagram.pdf), but these are my notes for IOS SDK, and I admit I have not tried this in Android).

Comment: Thanks. It is useful to see if AWS *thinks* I'm authenticating.

Comment: The link to your diagrams you reference is returning a 404.

Comment: @chapeljuice thank-you.  It was pointing to a defunct branch which was lost when I did some cleanup.  Sorry.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I finally determined that I was missing calls to set the tokens into the credentials provider:

```
    final CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = getCredentialsProvider(applicationContext);

    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put(Constants.COGNITO_USER_POOL_LOGIN_STRING, cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

where Constants.COGNITO_USER_POOL_LOGIN_STRING is like "cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + MY_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID. After doing that, a TransferUtility object was able to download with authentication. The TransferUtility was previously obtained like this (edited):

```
CognitoCredentialsProvider cp = . . .
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cp);
TransferUtility s3transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
```